# MySQL search for a number in VARCHAR field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field in my database that contain comma separated values these values are numbers, and I am trying to do a search and count the number of times that a number appears in that column throughout the column,

```
$sql = "SELECT sector_id_csv, COUNT(sector_id_csv) as count FROM cv WHERE sector_id_csv LIKE '$sectorId'";
```

This seems slow and does not return any results, and I know the sector_id it is search exists in the table.

Comment: What value does `$sectorID` have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, this should work fine if you use `%` wildcards:

```
WHERE sector_id_csv LIKE '%$sectorId%'";
```

what tends to cause problems in this scenario, though, is the fact that a search for `50` will also find `501` `502` `503` and so on.

If you can rely on your comma separated list to have a trailing comma behind *every* entry, it would be more reliable to search for

`50,`

to catch that value only.

Comment: This will cause FULL TABLE SCAN to be performed. On large tables this will be really slow.

Comment: @FractalizeR yup. I think this approach will be slow no matter what, normalizing the table would definitely speed things up. But maybe it's fast enough - for smaller projects, data is easier to handle this way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer gave enough of basis to get it working, the table will never be massive.

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE CONCAT(',', sector_id_csv, ',') LIKE '%,$sectorId,%'
```

or

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('$sectorId', sector_id_csv);
```

This will ensure that your query returns only rows with sector id in given field. Provided that sector id-s in this field are comma separated.

Any query using LIKE or FIND_IN_SET will be slow as it cannot take advantage of indexes. Please consider putting all sector id-s in separate table.

Also for security reasons please remember to ensure that $sectorId is a number by casting it to int like that:

```
$sectorId = (int)$sectorId;
```

before using it in a query.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you need to pad the value with the `%` wildcard for LIKE to work?

```
$sql = "SELECT sector_id_csv, COUNT(sector_id_csv) as count FROM cv WHERE sector_id_csv LIKE '%".$sectorId."%'";
```

At least that's my understanding from reading this article, your use of wildcards will depend on your desired condition.

Answer (score 1):

...but if your scema was normalized you wouldn't need to jump through these hoops - and it would run **a lot** faster.

C.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the number could be at he beginning or the end too. So you need to do

```
WHERE sector_id_csv='$sectorId' OR sector_id_csv LIKE '%,$sectorId' OR sector_id_csv LIKE '$sectorId,%' OR sector_id_csv LIKE '%,$sectorId,%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*) from TABLENAME where FIND_IN_SET('VALUE',FILDNAME)>0;
```

Others u can use  instr, regexp....
It's advisable to have FILDNAME indexed.